# Как со страницы HTML набрать номер на мобильном ?

Tags: jquery, java, bluetooth

Как нажатием на кнопку ПОЗВОНИТЬ на странице, набрать номер на мобильном , подключенном по блютус к компьютеру ? Ну или хотя бы отправить SMS :)

Comment: Месье знает толк в извращениях? )))

Comment: Вариант 1. Найти уязвимость в браузере, написать эксплойт, который заодно будет набирать номер на мобильном, подключенном по блютус к компьютеру, ну или хотя бы отправлять SMS.  
Вариант 2. Запускать на компьютере программу, которая будет мониторить действия на веб-странице и отправлять телефону команды на звонок/SMS

Comment: для начала вам надо установить скайп и посмотреть как работает callto которая подменят на веб сайтах логин скайпа ссылкой на которую можно кликать. если я правильно понимаю для этого используется плагин который вместо логина скайп поставляет специальную ссылку (на файл? и прописывает отдельный content type который обрабатывается нужной вам программой). а вот взаимодействие с вашим телефоном организовать это уже задача посложнее т.к. моделей слишком много и универасльной программы для работы с ними небыло и не будет)

Comment: @jmu, блютус как бы и создавался для синхронизации с устройствами, это протокол. Связь через TCS вполне реально осуществить.

Comment: Похоже не один я знаю толк в извращениях :) ( http://telefum.com/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два варианта:

1. Написать плагин к браузеру (навроде скайповского плагина на линки телефонных номеров)
2. Послать запрос к серверу и на стороне сервера написать все что душа пожелает.

Comment: Написать плагин к браузеру - вот с этого места поподробнее :)

Comment: Для разработки плагина к Explorer'у - изучите [данный сайт](http://www.iegallery.com/Addons). Для хрома [фтыкаем сюда](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

Answer (score 1):

в линуксе несколько пакетов было на эту тему, я как понимаю есть сервер (скажем апач) на нем сайт, на сайте "позвонить" мобильник должен позвонить или отправить sms, для звонка там много конечно морочаться, websockets, html5/флэш audio поток и прочее, для смс все просто - запускаем скриптик и вуаля - готово (еще может быть есть какие-нибудь astrisk плагины, как для телефонов (эмуляция гарнитуры) так и для роутинга аудиопотока в веб.

Резюмирую:

- linux
- Astrisk
- asterisk-mobile
- плагин для трансляции в веб надо поискать/написать

Comment: ubuntu-server+asterix - это уже давно действующая модель.
Интересует возможность сделать это без сервера.

Comment: а мобилу к чему подключать будете ? если это сервис для пользователей то как сказал barmaley - расширения для всех браузеров.

Answer (score 1):

1) java ту не причем

2) если нужно набирать номера со своего сайта то плагин писать не обязательно. Достаточно зарегистрировать свой протокол(что весьма просто делаеться через реестр http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx)

И сделать ссылку

`<a href="callto:+380951234567">380951234567</a>`

Браузер запускает екзешник. А экзешник шлет AT команду ATD +380951234567

Comment: эээ... а кто веб-страничке даст править реестр?

Comment: Веб страничка реест править не может. Для этого делается .reg файл